# Sequence with 1 limit point

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose the image of some sequence has 1 limit point.

Convergent sequence, for example $a_n = \frac1n$, may have 1 limit point. I wonder, is there any divergent sequence with 1
limit point?

Comment: How about $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,...$

Answer (score 5):

Exactly what do you mean by *limit point*? If you mean a point that is **the** limit of the sequence, then of course a divergent sequence of real numbers has no limit point. If you mean a *cluster point*, however, then the answer is *yes*: an example is the sequence

$$\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle 0,1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0,9,\dots\rangle$$

in which

$$x_n=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
n,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

This is a divergent sequence with a single cluster point, $0$.

Comment: Damn, you are fast.

Comment: @copper.hat: Had a typo, though. (I remember thinking the same thing about Arturo. Frequently.)

Comment: Still amazing. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

How about

$$
a_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n \text{ even}\\ n, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the notion of divergence:

1- A sequence $a_n$ is divergent if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \pm \infty$. Then such a sequence cannot have another limit point that is not $\infty$;

2- A sequence $a_n$ is divergent if we can extract a subsequence $b_n$ from it such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \pm \infty$. With this notion of divergence your sequence can have multiple limit points, as noted by other users. In particular the sequence

$a_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n \text{ even}\\ n, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$

is divergent and has 0 as a limit point. 
In my personal experience the first notion of divergence is the most commonly used.